# Feather Texture Edges of Cylinder

Tags: texturing

[image]

With this vortex I'm making, I would like to feather those edges but I'm not quite sure the correct node set up. The vortex was made using a Cylinder mesh with the caps deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make "endcaps" for your cylinder by using a Wave Texture separated on it's lengthwise axis (in this case Y) and a ColorRamp - Note the *very* small scale of the Wave Texture - you will have to shrink it until there is only one "Wave" line, and then invert it with a ColorRamp so the "outsides" are black instead of white. I also used a Vector Math node to add the vectors from a (also Y-axis) stretched noise texture to "deform" the endcaps, and give them that feathered look. Note that the vector addition requires you to move the Wave Texture "back to center" by using a mapping node, moving it -0.5 on the Y axis.

[image: Caps]

Once you have the look you like, just multiply it over the alpha you are already using as part of your existing material (assuming you have one - it looks like it from your screenshot).

[image: AlphaCaps]